# Generate python3-config for pyenv + virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyenv

I'm trying to compile a library which takes the path to `python3-config` as one of it's arguments i.e. `-DPYTHON_CONFIG=python3-config` then sets various compiler flags based on it's contents. This file exists on my machine for `python 3.6` as that's the system version, but I'm trying to build the library using a `python 3.7.1` `pyenv+virtualenv` so I need to generate a corresponding `python3-config` for each specific python environment. How can I do this? All I've found so far is this file is generated by `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Edit: I've discovered that pyenv `python3-config` exists in `/home/david/.pyenv/shims/python/python3-config` but this version is much smaller than the version from `/usr/bin/python3-config`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself

Assuming `pyenv` is installed in the recommended way, and `python 3.7.1` is installed using `pyenv` then the paths to the required `bin` and `config` are:

> ~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/bin/python3.7
>
> ~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/bin/python3.7-config

`python3.7-config` is a script which takes arguments like --includes and returns the info the build system requires to build and link the python extension for the specified pyenv, i.e.

> $ ~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/bin/python3.7-config --includes
>
> -I/home/david/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/include/python3.7m